# Why is java.io.File's prefixLength transient?

Tags: java, file

`java.io.File`'s `prefixLength` can be used as an identifier for what type of path the `File` contains. Why is the `prefixLength` field `transient`?

Comment: `java.io.File` implements `Serializable` which means that all its fields should be serialized. That said, I don't see any field called `prefixLength` in the docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Comment: @alfasin It's in [the source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/io/File.java#File.0prefixLength)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`transient` is used to indicate the field will be ignored by the standard java serialisation process. In this case it is handled explicitly by the `readObject()` method instead. This, and `path` are both handled in the same way.

This is so that when objects are serialised between JVMs running on different platforms (Windows, Linux, etc) the `path` can be normalised using the platforms file system.

Comment: you mean *should* be ignored

Comment: @keyser it's exactly what I meant - thanks, corrected.

Comment: @keyser I don't know what he said originally but `transient` means it *will* be ignored by the standard Java serialization process.

Comment: I'm currently re-checking `File` because I thought that once the abstract path name has been created, I thought that the path name can't be changed. Can you guys elaborate more on this?

Comment: @EJP I incorrectly said _should not_ which is just wrong. Probably too early in the morning to be answering questions. _Will_ is even better.

Comment: @bimboxX `path` is only set in the constructors or the readObject() method. This means it will be set when the class is created or when the class is serialised. From a users point of view it cannot be changed.